# PHP Object property does not come out with echo statement

Tags: php, arrays, oop

I am having problem to display the property of the object. This makes me puzzle. I did some search on the net including the manual but I am really not sure what is wrong with my code. I believe the way I called is correct. By the way, this is part of my code:

```
print_r($this->data());
echo ' pwd:'.$this->data()->pwd;
```

First line displays

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [pwd] => MyPass) )
```

My second line of code displays

```
 pwd:
```

I don't know which part is wrong. I just want to display the property but could not get the property of the object. Could anyone help me to explain this to me?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please include your Class and instantiation of your object

Comment: `$data = $this->data(); echo $data[0]->pwd;` if you have latest PHP versions you could do like `echo $this->data()[0]->pwd;`

Comment: The `$this->data()` is an array, ie why you are seeing an array. The first element of array with key 0 is the standardclass object, which have a property pwd. Let me know if that helps!

Comment: @HariKT Looks like `$this->data()[0]-pwd` is not for me because it generates internal server error. I believe mine is not the latest PHP version. But `$data = $this->data(); echo $data[0]->pwd;` just print nothing.

Comment: @HariKT sorry my bad, `$data = $this->data(); echo $data[0]->pwd;` works for me! That helps!

Comment: @UserProg so I have answered your question below, so you can mark as answer. And I wonder whether the internal server error was occurred due to missing `>` after `[0]-pwd`. Thanks!

Comment: @HariKT I need to check further on that. And I have accepted your answer. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$this->data()` is an array, ie why you are seeing an array. The first element with key `0` is the standardclass object, which have a property pwd. So you could access it as

```
$data = $this->data(); 
echo $data[0]->pwd;
```

if you have latest PHP version (5.5+) you could do like

```
echo $this->data()[0]->pwd;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

`$this->data()->pwd;`

You are calling a method and a property...as far as I know you can't do that.

You just need to use `$this->pwd`

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

Comment: Sorry maybe I have used the wrong term. `pwd` is not the property of the class. `data()` is the method in the class and it returns the object from another class. Inside object there is `pwd` that I want to print out.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would go about echoing an object in php, in my example i created an array, added the object to the array, encoded the array, and then finally echoed out the array with the object in it.

```
$posts= array();
 class Item {
   public $title = "";
   public $firstName = "";
   public $lastName = "";
   public $email = "";
   public $id = "";
```

}

```
$e = new Item();        
    $e->title = $title;
    $e->firstName  = $firstName;
    $e->lastName = $lastName;
    $e->email = $email;
    $e->id = $id;
    array_push($posts, $e);
json_encode($posts);
echo json_encode($posts);
```